# C# a TimeSpan in attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

So I'm trying to use an [add-on](https://github.com/Joe4evr/Discord.Addons/tree/master/src/Discord.Addons.Preconditions/Ratelimit), not created by me.

[image: But I get this error]

So I understand that the arguments needs to be constants and a `TimeSpan` is not a constant, but a `TimeSpan` is a required argument.

[image: required argument.]

Yes, there is one overload which does not take a `TimeSpan` as an argument, but that overload is no good for my use.

So is this a mistake by the developer of that add-on, or am I doing something wrong an it is actually somehow possible to pass a `TimeSpan` as an argument?

Comment: I think you can contact him directly [here](https://github.com/Joe4evr/Discord.Addons/issues/new).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to pass a timespan to an attribute like that. You need to use the other overload, which is probably provided in order to work around the timespan issue:

```
[RateLimit(3, 10.0 / 60.0, Measure.Minutes)]
```

Note however that the timespan constructor still may make sense, depending on the framework. You can directly instantiate attributes using `new` because they are regular classes. Maybe the framework offers a way to supply the attribute in another way, like [global filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution) in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET MVC Core.

Comment: Oh sh*t, I didn't realize I could use fractional minutes. I was just thinking that 1 minute being the smallest amount is way too big. Thanks a lot man! Also had to add a `d` after one of the numbers.

Comment: @xanatos: Thanks for the hint, I corrected my answer.